# Doing A is preferable to doing B. = Doing A rather than doing (?) / do (?) B is advisable

Tags: subjects, gerund-vs-infinitive

> In that situation I would rather do A than (I would) (do) B.

If the verb 'do' appears after 'rather' it has to be in the bare infinitive, not in the gerund.

How about that other way of expressing the same idea?

> Doing A rather than (do) (?) / (doing) (?) B is the course of action I would choose in that situation.*

The verb 'do' being itself the subject of the verb 'be' has to be in the gerund. If that same verb appears again after 'rather', should it also be in the gerund this time rather than in the bare infinitive?

Answer (score 1):

You would say "Doing A rather than doing be" because of parallel structure because you are comparing two things.

Use parallel structure:

- With a coordinating conjunction such as and, but, or, nor, yet
- With a pair of correlative conjunctions such as either . . . or or not only . . . but also

  - With a word introducing a comparison, usually than or as

http://www.grammar.com/rule-of-parallel-structure/

Comment: something that obscures the issue of this rule is a sentence like: 'It is advisable to do A rather than do B.' , where 'do' is in the full infinitive first and in the bare infinitive next (because 'to' is not repeated, is understood, isn't it)?!

Comment: @user58319 A second *to* is optional.